# Raspberry Pi 3 with ASP.NET Core and USB Serial Connection

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

I'm trying to create a web server that exposes some serial communication interfaces. The server is written in ASP.NET Core running on Windows 10 IoT, it is connected via USB to an Arduino. Information is sent via serial port to the arduino by the web service over time.

The issue I'm running into is that the only working examples of serial communication in this fashion are written for the Universal Windows Platform. Specifically the [Win10IoT Serial Sample](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/SerialUART). My problem is that the API's used in that example aren't available in an ASP.NET Core application.

What do I need to do in order to enable sending serial data to my arduino from my Raspberry Pi? Is this a feature that Windows 10 IoT plans to provide or should another platform be adopted to implement this.

There are two solutions to the problem I'm currently facing.

1. Create and host an ASP.NET website in a Universal Windows Platform app

or

2. Establish serial communication between ASP.NET Core and the USB/Serial port.

The second option is preferred, but simply solving this problem would be fantastic!

Comment: Is [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2015/11/27/bringing-asp-net-website-to-run-as-a-windows-10-app-and-access-camera-using-uwp-api/) helpful?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT unfortunately no. It would solve the problem but requires implementing an additional layer in my solution that should not exist. I would expect the limitations of the platform to go the other way around, so this is a weird road block to hit for me.

Comment: You may need to consider the first solution.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT do you have an example of that first solution? I read that [that is not possible](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eb9c3cb0-8ac3-4df6-9b87-7d56fe8311f1/uwpis-it-possible-to-use-aspnet-core-in-a-universal-windows-application?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: @wind-rider Maybe [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2015/11/27/bringing-asp-net-website-to-run-as-a-windows-10-app-and-access-camera-using-uwp-api/) is a possible way.

Comment: Currently, there is no support of serial device access from ASP.NET core. You can vote up [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/21810).

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I was looking for a way to "Create and host an ASP.NET website in a Universal Windows Platform app". The use case for that is that I want to run e.g. a REST service as a Background App on Windows IoT Core so that it can access UWP APIs and so that it is managed by the operating system.
It looks like you suggested that approach (Jul 27 at 0:46) but didn't explain how - that's why I asked for an example. I'm not looking for a "Hosted Web App" which sounds similar but is something completely different.